# Delete Duplicate Elements from Xml and should not delete null values inXSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I would appreciated if someone could help me to create xslt to remove duplicates nodes from XML based on duplicated element's value(PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName) but not empty values.

I want to remove all the duplicate elements except null values(PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName) from the GStep/Step

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Document>
       <Meta>
         <GpsFile>notepad_may_30_file</GpsFile>
         <GpsId>36fa4fe8-9691-4a7f-8bc1-9543f6b7d29a</GpsId>
          <ExePath>
             <ExePath1>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe</ExePath1>
          </ExePath>
        </Meta>
         <Process>
            <GStep DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
             <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>3</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>4</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>5</Step-ID>      
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>6</Step-ID>      
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Replace...\tCtrl+H</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>12</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>13</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>14</Step-ID>      
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Replace...\tCtrl+H</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>15</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>
            </Step>
          </GStep>
          <GStep DialogName="Replace">
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>8</Step-ID>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />      
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>9</Step-ID>      
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>10</Step-ID>      
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>16</Step-ID>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
             </Step>
           </GStep>
         </Process>
       </Document>
```

Actually expecting a result like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Document>
       <Meta>
         <GpsFile>notepad_may_30_file</GpsFile>
         <GpsId>36fa4fe8-9691-4a7f-8bc1-9543f6b7d29a</GpsId>
          <ExePath>
             <ExePath1>C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\notepad.exe</ExePath1>
          </ExePath>
        </Meta>
         <Process>
            <GStep DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
             <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>3</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />      
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>4</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>5</Step-ID>      
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Edit</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>6</Step-ID>      
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Replace...\tCtrl+H</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
            </Step>
            <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>12</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
            </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Untitled - Notepad">
              <Step-ID>15</Step-ID>     
              <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>
            </Step>
          </GStep>
          <GStep DialogName="Replace">
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>8</Step-ID>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />      
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>9</Step-ID>      
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>Cancel</PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName>     
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>10</Step-ID>      
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
             </Step>
             <Step DialogName="Replace">
                <Step-ID>16</Step-ID>     
                <PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName />     
             </Step>
           </GStep>
         </Process>
       </Document>
```

Xslt code snippet.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="ControlNameInfo" match="Step" use="PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName"/>
     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="GStep/Step[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('ControlNameInfo', PlayBack-- 
        ControlInfo-ControlName)[1]))]"/>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Should delete the duplicate values but should not delete empty **PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName**

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is XSLT 2 or 3 and you want to use the key function it seems you need to add a predicate to only check non-empty `Step`s and you additionally need to use the third argument of the `key` function to restrict search to the ancestor `GStep`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:key name="dups" match="Step[normalize-space(PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName)]" use="PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName"/>

  <xsl:template match="Step[normalize-space(PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName)][not(. is key('dups', PlayBack--ControlInfo-ControlName, ancestor::GStep)[1])]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bEzkTcp

Comment: Hi Thanks for response. If i want to do in version 1.0. Its giving exception in visual studion in version 2.0 and 3.0  as below 


studioXslTransformException
---------------------
Expected token ')', found 'is '.

Comment: Then don't tag as xslt-2